# How do you set a belongsTo association and save in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For context I'm using the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` and `DS.ActiveModelSerializer`.

## Issue

When I set a `belongsTo` property on my Ember model, and then call `.save()` in the next line, the payload to the server doesn't include the object id.

## Code

This is what I currently have in my controller:

```
#coffeescript

someChildObject = @get('model')

newParentObject = @store.createRecord 'parent'
newParent.set('child', someChildObject)
newParent.save()
```

I'd expect this to be sent to the server:

```
{ parent: { child_id: someId } }
```

## Workaround

I have found that if do the following it works:

```
#coffeescript

someChildObject = @get('model')

newParentObject = @store.createRecord 'parent'
newParent.set('child', someChildObject)

newParent.get('child').then ->
  newParent.save()
```

If I do the above it works, so I guess I need to wait for something but the above way can't be the correct way of waiting.

So, how does one set a `belongsTo` and then `.save()` correctly?